# Firefox spacing is different and erratically different?

Tags: html, css, firefox, horizontal-scrolling, spacing

I created horizontally scrolling div to display all my photos on a long carousal/film strip type display.

[How the div is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHEfW.jpg)

On Google Chrome and Safari, the 0px left margin between the images coded as list items displays perfectly. However, on Firefox, the spacing is huge, random and erratic. The spacing is so odd that it also prevents the later photos from being displayed as well. (Also the pesky scrollbar on the bottom shows up only in Firefox but I'll live with that if I can just fix the spacing)

[This is how it looks on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8c2L.jpg)

PLEASE SOMEONE HELP, THIS IS DRIVING ME MAD.

This is my HTML

```
<section id="photocontainer">

    <ul>

        <li> 

            <div class="initialspace"></div> 

        </li>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18873365401" title="Scotia In The Fog by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5483/18873365401_46f0a40ce6_c.jpg" alt="Scotia In The Fog"></a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18661212110" title="Rosewood Carpark by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3842/18661212110_92cb80e80b_b.jpg" alt="Rosewood Carpark"></a></li>

        <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18873364491" title="Liquor &amp; Lights by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c4.staticflickr.com/4/3878/18873364491_d9ac0869b1_z.jpg" alt="Liquor &amp; Lights"></a>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18844333466" title="Purple City Hall by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3696/18844333466_d921e2f71b_b.jpg" alt="Purple City Hall"></a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18249959233" title="Too Cool by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3718/18249959233_4d3a12a9af_c.jpg" alt="Too Cool"></a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18682867498" title="Darby&#x27;s Window by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5517/18682867498_9a7f33bc0b_z.jpg" alt="Darby&#x27;s Window"></a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18682866998" title="Cotton Candy Skies by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5462/18682866998_25526d0459_o.jpg" alt="Cotton Candy Skies"></a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18873364871" title="Woodwards by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3902/18873364871_021cc9d56a_b.jpg" alt="Woodwards"></a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18682866698" title="Gastown by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c4.staticflickr.com/4/3783/18682866698_87518c3ccb_o.jpg" alt="Gastown"></a></li>

        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/zennawong/18249957443" title="Grand Library by Zenna Wong, on Flickr" target="blank"><img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5495/18249957443_eba1e6e4d3_b.jpg" alt="Grand Library"></a></li>





    </ul>

</section>
```

This is the CSS for it

```
#photocontainer {
height: 37.5em;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: auto; 
width: 910em;
}

#photocontainer li {
margin-left: 0px;
}

img {
height: 100%;
}

.initialspace {
width: 15.7em;
height: 37.5em;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: [here is a demo of the code in question](http://test.zennawong.com/ZennaWongPortfolioWebsite/streetphotography.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `li` style from `inline-block` to `inline`.

```
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe something so simple was throwing it off completely.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The large spaces is caused by the images not expanding to fill the entire width of the `li`. To fix this, set:

```
li img {
    width: 100%;
}
```